# SQL SELECT or CROSS JOIN Multiple Accounts and SUM values within columns by row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables

```
Table1APPLES
Table2ORANGES
Table3BANANAS
```

within each of these tables are Fruits with a Price and Quantity

```
    TABLE1APPLES:

    *Fruit*     *Price*    *Quantity*
----------------------------------------
     GreenApple   $5          8
     RedApple     $3          7


    TABLE2ORANGES:

    *Fruit*     *Price*    *Quantity*
----------------------------------------
     Oranges      $3          8    

    TABLE3BANANAS:

    *Fruit*     *Price*    *Quantity*
----------------------------------------
    YellowBanana  $5          9
    GreenBanana   $4          8
```

I want to find every combination of these fruits along with a summed price and quantity.

Example:

```
 Fruit       Price  Quantity    Fruit   Price   Quantity     Fruit          Price    Quantity    TotalPrice   TotalQuantity
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 Green Apple  $5       8         Orange   $3         8        Yellow Banana  $5       9          $13          25
 Green Apple  $5       8         Orange   $3         8        Green Banana   $4       8          $12          24

 Red Apple    $3       7         Orange   $3         8        Yellow Banana  $5       9          $11          24
 Red Apple    $3       7         Orange   $3         8        Green Banana   $4       8          $10          23
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What happened to red apples?

Comment: You need a cartesian product. Google SQL cross join.

Comment: @IanS made the update with Red Apples

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, what you want is called cartesian join. In mysql the simplest way to achieve it is to join the 3 tables without any join condition:

```
select *
from Table1APPLES
join Table2ORANGES
join Table3BANANAS
```

Comment: what about the TotalPrice and TotalQuantity?

Comment: You just add the 3 price and quantity fields.

Comment: Also I need something to JOIN the tables on so instead  Ive been able to do a 'SELECT * FROM TABLE1APPLES, TABLE2ORANGES, TABLE3BANANAS'  to get results for everything.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to play around with it and got this.

```
    SELECT *,
    TABLE1APPLES.PRICE + Table2ORANGES.Price + Table3BANANAS.Price AS TotalAmount,
    Table1APPLES.Quantity + Table2ORANGES.Quantity + Table3BANANAS.Quantity AS Quantity
    FROM TABLE1APPLES, Table2ORANGES, Table3BANANAS
```